# Child class post method to return different template and context

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to take the same form input and use it to do calculations (using different urls) for different products and send product results to a product template

I tried having a base class with get and post methods from which child classes(different product urls) will inherit especially the post method to remain DRY

```
from .models import InputForm

class InputView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'input.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = InputForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            a =cleaned_data['mbr_l']
            b =cleaned_data['es_l']
            c =cleaned_data['wic_l']
            d =cleaned_data['br2_l']

            length = a + b + c + d

            qty = 0.8*length

            return render(request, 'result.html',  {'qty': qty})


        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

class B(InputView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qty2 = super().post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

        return super().render(request, 'result2.html',  {'qty2': qty2})
url conf:
urlpatterns = [
    path('product1', InputView.as_view()),
    path('product2',B.as_view()),
 ]

templates:

template1
<td>{{qty1}}</td>

template2
<td>{{qty2}}</td>
```

I expect the url product2 in url conf to do calculation and send context(qty2) to results2.html but it always renders results.html with qty which is correct because B is inheriting InputView and all methods.I dont really expect the call to super of render method to be valid but that was the last of my many trials.

Comment: correction...self.cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data to cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data

Comment: Please fix your indentation. And show your URLs and the template.

Comment: You should split your template into another block. Btw, `super().render()` I'm not sure that super() include this method. Please update your question.